# Haskell: "Hello, World" weighs 2MB

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am just doing baby steps in haskell. I have downloaded Win64 bit version, pulled off some tutorial and created a .hs file

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

after compiling it with

```
.\ghc.exe -o hello hello.hs
```

I noticed the output file of a simple program running "Hello, World!" weighs almost 2MB. I am clearly sure that comes out from not understanding how Haskell works, however - is it anyhow possible to compile the source file so that it's not that fat? I assume Haskell added zillions of redundant libraries which are not required.

Can someone provide me insight on that compiler? I'm not even sure how to ask <strike>Google</strike> some search engine about that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please close, thanks for sharing the link